# Executar função apenas uma vez

Tags: javascript, jquery

A princípio, já vi algumas questões semelhantes a essa por aqui, mas praticamente nenhuma delas se enquadra/não funciona em meu cenário. É o seguinte: preciso que uma script seja executado (no meu caso, um botão ser clicado automaticamente) apenas uma vez (possivelmente, gravando algum cookie, eu acredito...) quando um usuário acessar a página em questão e desabilitar esse mesmo script para qualquer acesso subsequente ou refresh na página. Como posso proceder?

Comment: É possível fazer isso utilizando `cookies` ou o `localStorage`. Mas é possível limpar esses dados e o botão ser ativado novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Salva no banco de dados se ele clicou ou não. Se você quer que ele nunca mais aperte o botão é necessário salvar no banco de dados pois cookies podem ser apagados, o usuário pode acessar de outro computador. No seu lugar eu faria uma tabela que armazenaria 0 ou 1, se estiver 0 é porque ele n clicou, se tiver 1 então ele já clicou, então eu não colocaria nem o HTML do botão na pagina ou eu colocaria um `disabled` no botão.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, Daniel! Consegui agora há pouco! Abraços!